# UIDatePicker return value in 24-hour-format

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to iPhone development and now working on my first app. I have an UIDatePicker on a view and, if the user clicks on save, the current time of the date picker should be saved in the database (in format hh:mm).

Now, the problem is that my UIDatePicker has a 24-hour-format to choose the desired hours and minutes (I configured this by setting the iPhone settings in the simulator to "Switzerland" and "German"). If I choose, for example, 17:00 in the date picker, the following code generates 5:00 in NSLog:

```
NSDateFormatter *datePickerFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[datePickerFormat setDateFormat:@"hh:mm"];
NSString *datePickerStringToSave = [datePickerFormat stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
NSLog(@"%@", datePickerStringToSave);
```

Is it possible that the date picker returns the selected time in 24-hour format? Or can I configure the NSDateFormatter to show the returned time in 24 hours? I already tried to set the "Local" setting in the attributes inspector of the date picker to my country and language, but that doesn't work...

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: There is no UIDateSwitcher class in the SDK...

Comment: Already rectified, I naturally mean UIDatePicker. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem here is that the lowercase h in `@"hh:mm"` forces `datePickerFormat` into 12 hour mode. Try changing that line to:

```
[datePickerFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
```

For information on proper date format patterns, check out [this guide](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Thanks, but I think you probably misunderstood me. I absolutely can choose a 24-Hour-Date in the picker (the picker shows 24-hour-format) but, in the code above, the picker returns a 12-hour-format value, also when I have selected 17:00 or something like this.

Comment: Whoops, my fault on that! I've just edited my answer, and added a link to a guide on why this is the case.

Comment: No problem, sorry again about that first mistake! If this answers the question, would you mind hitting the check?

Comment: I have been finding for solution for 2 hours and this worked like a charm..Upvoted !!!

Answer (score 1):

A little late in my contribution but the fact that the date/time picker appears on the screen in 24hour format is due to the users date/time settings for the phone so UIDatepicker defaults to the users phone settings.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question, but this is the issue that I was googling that led me here. If your device clock is set to 24 hour mode, then "hh:mm" gives a 24 hour time. If set to 12 hours, then "hh:mm" gives a 12 hour time. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSDateFormatter *)GetPickerDateFormater
{
NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLocale *locale1 = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];
NSTimeZone *timeZone1 = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"IST"];
[formatter1 setTimeZone:timeZone1];
[formatter1 setLocale:locale1];
[locale1 release],
locale1 = nil;
return formatter1;
}

- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  txtToDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                        [[self GetPickerDateFormater] stringFromDate:DatepickerView.date]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time 
datePicker.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "NL")
```