# How to set NSTimeZone to Date picker controller in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimeinterval

I had created a Date picker controller and want to set the timeinterval to 12hrs pragmatically.

But i cant do that, i think this is very simple problem but please help me for this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSDateFormatter *detailsTimeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [detailsTimeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSLog(@"%@",[[detailsTimeFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] lowercaseString]); // this will return you the time with am/pm
```

Comment: I want to set the 12 hr timezone to date picker controller. So if you know give me that property. Thank you.

Comment: you need to use NSDateFormatter: `[datePickerFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360402/uidatepicker-return-value-in-24-hour-format
look the guide:
http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: with this we can get the string or date in that format but i want to apply the 12hr date format to date picker controller.

Comment: can you look at this topic, it may can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2894161/uidatepicker-problem-localizing/2918507#2918507

Comment: Hey thank you it is really good but tell me how to set the time zone... because with this it sets the english language and calender but not the time format to 12hr's ... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.X:

```
let detailsTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()
detailsTimeFormatter.timeStyle = .short
detailsTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
print(detailsTimeFormatter.string(from: Date()).lowercased())
```

Assign this time string date to the picker view.